# Why would having group write permission on a PHP script break it?

Tags: php, apache

I have a weird situation on a PHP system.

It mysteriously stopped working, and after some investigation, it looks like when a PHP scripts's permissions are set to allow group write, that script isn't "seen".

If group write permission is removed, the system starts to work again.

None of the other permissions are changing. Just group write.

I'm guessing this is some configuration of Apache or similar restriction which the hosting service has put on for security reasons. But how can I check? Or where can I find out more?

Is this likely to be an Apache config? And, if so, which Apache config. file defines it? Or, if not, where else might it be declared?

Is this a typical security measure, which has some rationale behind it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a typical security measure. This setup is called `phpSuExec`. Here you can find more regarding this mode [phpsuexec](https://www.studyhost.net/support/knowledgebase/66/What-is-phpsuexec.html).